# PySpark : foreachPartition with additional parameters

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to execute my function using `spark_df.foreachPartition()`, and I want to pass additional parameter but apparently the function supports only one parameter (the partition).

I tried to play with it and do something like this :

```
def my_function(row, index_name) :
    return True 

def partition_func(row): 
   return my_function(row, "blabla")

spark_df.foreachPartition(partition_func)
```

However, I'm getting a serialization error :

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: Cannot serialize socket object
```

How can I make this work? I know I can add parameters to my Spark Dataframe, but I think it's an ugly solution, sending it in function parameter is so much better.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the bug, your code works fine for me, also the function signature should be partition_func(rows) (A list of rows of each partition will be sent to that function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be other ways, but one simple approach could be to create a broadcast variable (or a container that holds any variables you may need), and then pass it to be used in your foreachPartition function. Something like this:

```
def partition_func_with_var(partition, broadcast_var):
  for row in partition:
    print(str(broadcast_var.value) + row.desc)

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"one"),(2,"two")],["id","desc"])

bv = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(" some extra variable ")

df.foreachPartition(lambda p: partition_func_with_var(p,bv))
```

Note that "passing a variable" has a little murky meaning here, as it is actually a [broadcast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.broadcast.html#pyspark.SparkContext.broadcast) operation, with all its consequences and limitations (read-only, sent once, etc.)

Comment: that's an interesting solution, it's solving my issue.